# Add custom atrribute to json response

Tags: laravel-5

I have model something like that with custom attribute

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    public function getExtraAttribute(){
        return 'some string'; //etc.
    }
}
```

And for controller method i have this

```
return MyModel::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

But i don't see 'extra' attribute on json response

P.s. extra isn't column from database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the attribute to `$appends`.

```
class MyModel extends Model {
    ...    
    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = ['extra'];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As per the docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

```
class User extends Model
{
     protected $appends = ['extra'];

     public function getExtraAttribute()
     {
        return $this->attributes['extra'] = 'some string...';
     }
}
```

Comment: Thans, so much!